# Hide iframe (which loads PHP function) until form button is clicked

Tags: php, html, iframe

I am trying to hide an iframe until the user fills in the fields on a web form and clicks the 'Submit' button. Is there a simple way to do this? I looked at some javascript/jQuery answers to related questions but could not utilise them unfortunately.

(The code itself works I just want to hide the iframe)

Here's my code:

```
<div class = "form11">

<form id = "embedform" action="itemb_sign.php" target="my-frame" method="post">

  <label for="fname1">Full Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="fname1"><br>

  <label for="femail1">Email:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="femail1"><br>

  <label for="fcnum1">Contact Number:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="fcnum1"><br>

  <label for="faddress1">Current Address:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="faddress1"><br><br>

   <input id = "b11" type="submit" class = "button11" value="Sign Now">
</form> 
</div>

<div>
<iframe id = "ifm" name="my-frame" height="1000" width="1000" src="itemb_sign.php"></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you just want to _hide_ the iframe that already shows the result of `itemb_sign.php` - or dou you want to _delay_ the request that loads `itemb_sign.php` from the server? Those are two fundamentally different things to begin with. _“I looked at some javascript/jQuery answers to related questions but could not utilise them unfortunately.”_ - you are still supposed to show us something that you actually tried.

Comment: I want to hide the iframe until the button is clicked, because the URL is retrieved through the php script, until then it just displays a 'no valid parameter' error.

Comment: _“until then it just displays a 'no valid parameter' error”_ - because you are loading the `itemb_sign.php` into the iframe on page load already, but via a GET request. So why don’t you just load a _different_ URL (of an “empty page”), or just `about:blank` in there initially?